# Are my files on the hard drive or on the PCB?

Tags: hard-drive

Stupid question but hey, I don't know the answer. If my dead hard drive can be repaired with a ROM/BIOS swap does that indicate that the only part I really need is the PCB? Or are my files on the hard drive itself like I originally thought?

Answer (score 1):

Your files are on the hard drive platters, but the drive's firmware is required to read those platters (without special recovery hardware and software).